# JMeter - Can I set report granularity at the command line?

Tags: jmeter

I have some JMeter tests, and they take different amounts of time.  I'd like to change the granularity of the reports without having to change the reportgenerator.properties file.  I read the documentation about generating reports, and I'm still not clear.  Do I do it something like -Jreportgenerator.properties.overall_granularity=10000?
Can/How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I found that the following worked for me in JMeter 3.2.....

```
jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000 -g testresults.jtl -o dashboard
```

This sets the granularity to 1 second for my report.

And another example,to give the report a granularity of 1 second and a different title e.g. My Report

```
jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000 -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.report_title="My Report" -g testresults.jtl
 -o dashboard
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here's a cite from the aforementioned file:

> THIS FILE SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED
>
> This avoids having to re-apply the modifications when upgrading JMeter
>    Instead only user.properties should be modified:
>    1/ copy the property you want to modify to user.properties from here
>    2/ Change its value there

Then, -D option overrides system property for JVM, that should look like

```
-Dreportgenerator.properties.overall_granularity=10000
```

you may add it stright to the command line when starting JMeter with standard script provided.

As far as I know, usually for JVM running JMeter the genuine configuration properties are looking exactly like this (system properties), so application of `-D` option must work.
Here's the kind of a proof from official [properties reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html):

> The properties present in jmeter.properties or
>   reportgenerator.properties should be set in the user.properties file.
>   These properties are only taken into account after restarting JMeter
>   as they are usually resolved when the class is loaded.

So that must be working, come back if not. :-)

**UPDATE:**
It turns out, the property name has been misspelled by topicstarter, the correct name is:

```
-Djmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=10000
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't use that and still used the default granularity

Comment: sorry, it's not clear, you didn't use _what_ exactly?

Comment: I tried adding -Dreportgenerator.properties.overall_granularity=10000, and jmeter didn't use that, it still used it's default granularity

Comment: But hold on, I just repeated what you used - and you used a wrong one.
You should have checked that: what's inside is "jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity", not the garbage you've posted.
I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

./jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000 -g /path/to/jtl/file -o /where/you/want/to/store/dashboard

This works perfectly in JMeter 4.0 and 5.0